# Unable to install primer3-py on python3 on AWS EC2 server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, installation, environment, primer3

I'm trying to make a streamlit app working with primer3 and the python file works fine on my PC. However I'm having trouble installing primer3-py on my ec2 server running Linux system.

The command that I run is:

`python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`

It gets an error like this:

```
primer3/src/primerdesign_py.c:30:13: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include    <Python.h>

             ^~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Just in case, I tried to run `pip3 install primer3-py` directly and led to the same error. It seemed that gcc is part of Cython, which I've already succeeded in installing.

I would be really grateful for any help! Thank you!